# Question about matrix powers and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

From this [textbook](https://mlstory.org/optimization.html):

[image]

Can someone explain the first equality in the fourth sentence? I'm not clear how $(I - aQ)^tv = (1 + a|\lambda_d|)^tv$.

Thank you!

Comment: Restricting to natural $t$, if we expand the left hand side, we get $\sum_{}{}(-aQ)^{t}v$. Since $v$ is an eigenvector of any power of $Q$, this sum is $\sum_{}{}(-a(-\lambda_{d}))^{t}v$, which can then be gathered into the power of the bracket shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that since $\lambda_d < 0$, we get $\lambda_d = - |\lambda_d|$. Then,
$$(I-\alpha Q)v = v- \alpha \lambda_d v = (1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)v.$$
And,
$$(I-\alpha Q)^2v = (I-\alpha Q)((1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)v) = (1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)(I-\alpha Q)v = (1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)^2v.$$
In general, (use induction)
$$(I-\alpha Q)^tv = (I-\alpha Q)^{t-1}((1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)v) = (1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)(I-\alpha Q)^{t-1}v = \cdots = (1 + \alpha |\lambda_d|)^t v .$$

Comment: Thank you! It was as simple as induction after all.